# How does this arrow function work?

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to Jquery and someone helped me with some code using an arrow function. I'm not sure I fully understand however how they work. I looked around online but none of the examples seem to look like this. I would really be grateful!

```
var parent = nested.first(x => x.level == level - 1);
```

EDIT: The code for method first().

```
Array.prototype.first = function (func) {
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    var item = this[i];
    if (func(item)) {
        return item;
         }
    }

    return null;
};
```

Comment: Equivalent to `function(x) { return x.level == level -1 }`. The function returns a boolean. MDN is a good reference ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: How is it returning a boolean? @Phil

Comment: Might be easier (and better for you) if you attempt to tell me how it's not ;)

Comment: I don't know what API that `first()` method belongs to (it's not jQuery or part of the `Array` prototype) but if I had to guess, it takes a [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)) function and returns the first value from a collection that the predicate returns `true` for. Similar to [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: @Phil So after staring at the code for a while I think I understand. Basically its taking nested.first as the input for the function. Then its checking whether the nested.first level == level - 1? Because its using an == which is roughly equal to, so it returns a boolean :)

Comment: I'd say it's more like `nested` is an array or other _iterable_ collection and the `first()` method iterates that collection, passing each item (`x)` into the callback function, halting iteration at the first positive match and returning that `x` value. Again, I'm only guessing though as you have not provided any hints as to the source of this `first()` method. Again, see `Array.prototype.find()` for what I _think_ is an equivalent JavaScript function

Comment: @Phil I will edit in source code for that first() method. Although I think you already guessed what it is.

Comment: You realise that `first()` implementation is exactly what `Array.prototype.find()` does, right?

Comment: @Phil I did not write this piece of code but I will go take a look at what find does because at the moment this first method is causing me a lot of problems. Thanks so much for the help! Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello to JS World :D

Let go with this `x => x.level == level - 1`

First character `x` before the arrow is a function argument. So `x =>` is equal to `function (x) {`.

Then we have in the same line `x.level == level - 1` - this is equal to `return x.level == level -1`. Why it is equal to `return`? Because if arrow function has no `{}` then it return the result of the expression.

The format of the arrow function is `argument => expression` which is equal to `function (argument) { return expression }` :) It is a handy shortcut.

More questions? Please ask.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The given code can be written in older JS Version as follows:-

```
var parent = nested.first(function(x){
  return x.level == level - 1
});
```

Hope the above make it clear for you. If not then feel free to comment, I will give more explanation.